# How do I send data to a central area?

Tags: java

I want to send how long a java application has been running to a central location which I can access. What would be the easiest way to do this?

This is a small project so I would rather not have to set up a server just for this - maybe some kind of cloud application like Dropbox or twitter?

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried so far??](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [Stashboard](http://www.stashboard.org/#documentation) and run this on google appengine and use google's data store.
Have a look at these APIs as well http://readthedocs.org/docs/stashboard/en/latest/restapi.html#services.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like
[Dropbox file upload/download with Java and Spring](http://agilesc.barryku.com/?p=83)

or maybe you could just send an email to a gmail account you setup just for that using simple mail protocols